# Trying to use aaa instruction

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm

I am new in assembly and is using TASM. I'm trying to use the `aaa` instruction, but whatever I do I can't seem to do it. I am adding `8` and `2`, and I've read something about `aaa`, but whatever I do I can't seem to print the characters `1` and `0`.

Here is my code:

```
.model small

.stack

.data

.code
main proc

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, '8'
    add al, '2'

    aaa
    or ax, 3030h

    mov ah, 02
    mov dl, ah
    int 21h

    mov ah, 02
    mov dl, al
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

    main endp
end main
```

Comment: Your program does not print anything on the `stdout`, so you cannot expect to see a result diplayed. To track down the results of your program, use `gdb` or any debugger that is able to step a program.

Comment: @perror: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm

Comment: i think i've printed the character, it's the mov ah, 02 instruction

Comment: Ah, you are under Windows... I assumed you were under Linux. You should have specified this.

Comment: From Intel's manual: _"Binary-coded decimal integers (BCD integers) are unsigned 4-bit integers with valid values ranging from 0 to 9"_. Neither `'8'` nor `'2'` are in the range 0 to 9.

Answer (score 2):

`Int 21/AH=02h` is a function that doesn't preserve the `AX` register. You have to store your result and to fetch it when you need it. Take care not to destroy `AX` by changing `AH` or `AL`!

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

    hold dw ?

.code
main proc

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 8
    add al, 2

    aaa
    or ax, 3030h
    mov hold, ax

    mov ax, hold
    mov dl, ah
    mov ah, 02
    int 21h

    mov ax, hold
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 02
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

    main endp
end main
```